# Got an error after associating EIP to my NAT Gateway in Terraform with modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an infrastructure in AWS using Terraform with modules. So I got 2 modules, one for my Nat Gateway and one for the EIP Creation and Association. In my main file, to associate the EIP to the NAT Gateway I use 2 output attributes of my NAT GW and EIP which are the ID of the NAT and the EIP ID, like this:

```
module "eip_assoc" {
  source = "../Modules/eip_assoc"
  nat_gw_qa = module.NAT_GW.aws_nat_gateway_id_output
  nat_gw_association = module.EIP.eip_one_id_output
}
```

Everything is ok with the rest of the infrastructure,  when I apply the main file it creates the resources in AWS and do the association of the EIP to the NAT GW but at the end of the consoles it shows an error like this:

"Error: Error associating EIP: InvalidNetworkInterfaceId.Malformed: Invalid id: "nat-0c15axxxxxxxxxx" (expecting "eni-...")"

So ok, it says I need the eni-... output from the NAT GW instead of the Allocation_id, I change the output to be the network_interface_id which returns the ENI ID of the NAT GW, but after that I got another different error:

Error: Error associating EIP: AuthFailure: You do not have permission to access the specified resource.

In this case, same as before, it creates the infrastructure in AWS and it does the association of the EIP to the NAT GW with no problem at all, but after looking for that error message in Terraform Documentation it says "Do not use network_interface to associate the EIP to aws_lb or aws_nat_gateway resources. Instead use the allocation_id available in those resources to allow AWS to manage the association, otherwise you will see AuthFailure errors."

So if I use the allocation ID it shows the error of expecting ENI ID, if use the ENI ID it says AuthFailure error, in both scenarios deploys the whole resources but got those error messages.

Comment: I think NAT GW does not have ENI. You just need to create EIP then point it to allocation_id in NatGW like this: allocation_id = element(aws_eip.eip_ngw.*.id, count.index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see from this snippet

```
    module "eip_assoc" {
    source = "../Modules/eip_assoc"
    nat_gw_qa = module.NAT_GW.aws_nat_gateway_id_output
    nat_gw_association = module.EIP.eip_one_id_output
    }
```

> In my main file, to associate the EIP to the NAT Gateway I use 2 output attributes of my NAT GW and EIP which are the ID of the NAT and the EIP ID

The problem is the sequence,  you have to have an EIP already or create a new one with the NAT gateway creation OR In other words, you can't have EIP created and NAT gateway created and then associate EIP with NAT gateway.

This is exactly why we can't swap the EIP of the NAT gateway once it is created.

quoting [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)

> You cannot disassociate an Elastic IP address from a NAT gateway after it's created. To use a different Elastic IP address for your NAT gateway, you must create a new NAT gateway with the required address, update your route tables, and then delete the existing NAT gateway if it's no longer required.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-working-with)

> To use the same Elastic IP address for the NAT gateway that you currently use for your NAT instance, you must first also disassociate the Elastic IP address from your NAT instance and then associate it with your NAT gateway when you create the gateway.

> Specify the subnet in which to create the NAT gateway, and select the allocation ID of an Elastic IP address to associate with the NAT gateway.

Comment: In my case, I was getting the `Resource.AlreadyAssociated` error, but the link to the AWS docs here helped me understand I didn't need to create a network interface myself to associate the NAT to an EIP, because AWS automatically creates the interface for you. So, I was causing the issue by trying to associate the EIP to both the interface and to the NAT.